# How to get current position of where you are typing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, position, typing

I want to be able to see where I am typing in the box in proportion to the page. Ie. if I type an "L" in the text box, what is the current position on the page in pixels top/left.

I retrieved the current input positon of the field with:

```
  var field = document.getElementById("field");
  var boxX = field.offsetLeft;
  var boxY = field.offsetTop;
```

I just can't figure out current position in pixels of the location of the last letter typed in the field.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
  <input id="field" type="text"/>
```

JavaScript

```
var boxX =field.offsetHeight;
var boxY= field.offsetLeft;

document.getElementById("field").addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    console.log('Caret at: ', e.target.offsetLeft + e.target.selectionEnd);
    console.log('Caret at: ', e.target.offsetTop + e.target.selectionEnd);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but it doesn't seem to be working.